# Is it possible to make mesh with dissolve shader not mask geometry behind it?

Tags: shaders, masking

I have a dissolve shader in one of my projects, but I have a problem that when the mesh turns invisible from the shader effect, the mesh still mask some geometry behind it. Is it possible to make it not do that?

At least Unity has a "render queue" setting that let's you fix issues like this, but I haven't found anything similar in Blender yet. Another option of course is that if you can control Z buffer writes, you could make it not write if the pixel output is transparent. Not sure if Blender let's you do that either.

EDIT: Here is a picture of the shader nodes:
[image]

I also noticed that the shadow doesn't dissolve either. Also I'm using Eevee

Comment: No reasonable dissolve effect should mask geometry, unless you want it to.  You should probably show us the shader nodes you're using, and let us know your desired rendering engine (Eevee v Cycles.)

Comment: There are a few unknowns outstanding, here, before we can answer you accurately. Probably the simplest way to fill us in would be to share a representative file on https://blend-exchange.com/ . If you embedded an illustration of the disappointing result in your post, too,  that might clue us in before committing to a download.

Comment: I agree with previous comments, usually making one mesh disappear should not mask other geometry. But without seeing how this dissolve shader is realized in your project, it is hard to find out what you might have gotten wrong there. Are you using a _Transparent BSDF_ node or a _Holdout_ node?

Comment: I edited the question to add picture of the shader nodes